# Process Builder or Apex Trigger to Write Contact Field Value to Account when Condition is Met

Tags: apex, process-builder

The functionality I'm looking for is as follows. When an account contact relation is created check to see the Account.Field 1 is populated, if not then set Account.Field 1 = to Contact.Field 1, otherwise do nothing.

I seem to be able to get all the way to the step where I'd like to write the value in process builder but I can't reference contact.Field 1 at that time, only the picklist values of Account.Field 1.

Is there a way to do this in process builder? If not is it fairly trivial with apex?

Picture of current process builder workflow being triggered by the account contact relationship entity.
[image]

Comment: You can't trigger on AccountContactRole. Is this a custom object? Can you [edit] your question to show us a screenshot of what you have so far?

Comment: Sure thing. Added the screenshot. It's not a contact role table sorry... it's the account contact relation table. Similar to contact role on opps.